# Check the sqlite user_version on the server to update iOS app

Tags: ios, sqlite, parse-platform

I have this code:

```
-(int)queryUserVersion: (sqlite3*) db {
    // get current database version of schema
    static sqlite3_stmt *stmt_version;


   if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "PRAGMA user_version;", -1, &stmt_version, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while(sqlite3_step(stmt_version) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            databaseVersion = sqlite3_column_int(stmt_version, 0);
            NSLog(@"%s: version %d", __FUNCTION__, databaseVersion);
        }
        NSLog(@"%s: the databaseVersion is: %d", __FUNCTION__, databaseVersion);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%s: ERROR Preparing: , %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(db) );
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt_version);

    return databaseVersion;
}
```

I can check the sqlite `user_version` that the user has on the iPhone Documents directory. I have the SQLite DB previous downloaded. I want to know everytime of user loads the app if the local SQLite `user_version` is the same of the SQLite `user_version` that I have on my server, if they are different it downloads the new version.

How can I check the SQLite `user_version` before download it?

**UPDATE**

I was thinking about this, I'm using the `Parse API` for some features on my app so i decided do this system:

1. I stored the `user_version` sqlite value on the Parse Webservices to update it manualy.
2. I check with localize the iPhone language to know what DB I want to download (I have the same DB with 2 languages)
3. I check if it is the 1st time running the APP or not with `NSUserDefaults`.
4. If it is the first time it gonna check the language and then download the correct DB from my server.
5. If isn't the first time running the app I'll check on the Parse what is the current user_version and then compare it with the local `user_version` sqlite database on the iPhone. If it has a higher value it'll download the DB to update it.

**New Problem:** When I check the user_version on the `Parse`, I use a query `FindObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` (assync) so... it will run the app before checking the user_version and do the DB download. How can I handle it? I already tried with a `NSTimer`..

Code:

```
-(void)checkUserVersion{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"sqliteversion"]; //1
    // NSNumber *n=databaseVersion;
    [query whereKey:@"user_version" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[databaseVersion integerValue]]];//2
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {//4
        if (!error && [objects count]>0) {

            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                valor1=[[object objectForKey:@"Value"]intValue];
                user_version=[NSNumber numberWithInt:valor1];


            }

        }
    }];}
```

Comment: Are you asking about sqlite version (the database) as 3.7.15?

Comment: No, `PRAGMA user_version`. It can be modified manually.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're trying to do here is provide a set of data to your app, and have your app check to see if there's new data when it launches.

My advice would be to find another way than something within the sqlite data file for your app to use to see if there's new data on the server.  There's really no good way to see what's in that file without downloading it. Better is to have something on the server your app can query to find out if it needs to download new data.

I would recommend doing something like using the timestamp on the file. If you do this properly, you could likely take advantage of `NSURLCache` to take care of some of the logic for you.

Good luck!

Comment: So... what is the normal approach when developers want to upgrade the DB of an app which they have released?

Comment: Pretty much what I described above. Or did I misunderstand what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm really suprise I have to tell you. I've been searching for a solution for this on the last 2 days and it's the first time I see something like that, after checking many forums/posts.

I still have the same problem, how can I check the timestamp on the sqlite file on the server before compare it with the actual sqlite app file?

Comment: I think you were being too specific in your question; it's really a problem anyone has regardless of if sqlite is involved or not. In any case, if you use `NSURLRequest` properly, you get the logic for free - you'll get the on-disk file if it's current, otherwise the newer one from the server. Assuming your HTTP server is set up correctly, too. Lots of details here: http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539220/parse-com-app-goes-forward-before-i-get-the-value-i-want-async-ios