# Parse.com app goes forward before i get the value I want (async) iOS

Tags: ios, asynchronous, parse-platform

I use a query FindObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock (assync) to get a value from webservice... I want that value on the appdelegate before the app loads. I'm trying do it but he still load the app before check the webservices to get the value. How can I handle it? I already tried with a NSTimer..

I called this method in `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` :

```
-(void)checkUserVersion{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"sqliteversion"]; //1
    // NSNumber *n=databaseVersion;
    [query whereKey:@"user_version" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[databaseVersion integerValue]]];//2
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {//4
        if (!error && [objects count]>0) {

            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                valor1=[[object objectForKey:@"Value"]intValue];
                user_version=[NSNumber numberWithInt:valor1];


            }

        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Don't issue the PFQuery for the background, instead of `findObjectsInBackground`, use `findObjects`, and it will block execution of the rest of your code until the fetch finishes. HOWEVER: this will delay the start of your application, and be frustrating for your users. I also believe that the OS may terminate the application load if it takes too long. I've seen crashes caused by failure to launch. You have been warned

Comment: It was really nice if the people that downvote explain why and what is the problem with the question. It's easy to downvote... but it's hard explain it.

Comment: I agree man. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to evaluate why it's necessary to have this information from Parse.com before launch. Also, it can mean many things to say "before launch", and there are many solutions that don't involve doing "everything" before the first view is attached to the window and shown.

That said...run the PFQuery fetch in the foreground. Doing this will block execution of the rest of your code, though. Instead of `findObjectsInBackground` just use the `findObjects` method of PFQuery. I would advise against doing this though, and instead try to find out a way to wait for the query to return while the app is already loaded.  Maybe you could suspend user interaction but display a loading indicator or something?

Comment: I only need 2 seconds to check the value and compare it, i'll try, thank you

Comment: well maybe parse is slow to respond next Tuesday and it makes a lot of people angry :-)  Just sayin, 2 seconds is a guesstimate and a best case scenario

Comment: It worked, it's not the best option maybe because it freezes for 2 or 3 seconds, but it solve the main question, I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run any code in your app before it finishes launching.  If the value is critical for your app to begin working you'll have to show a "waiting for data" message.

Comment: I didn't explain it well, I want call that method on the: `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{`

Comment: jsd's answer is still valid. You shouldn't be blocking the app during launch for this purpose. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: checking the sqlite user_version to know if the user needs to download a new version of the database. If I don't do this during the launch I'll do it when?

Comment: You could do it after the app launches, and if necessary download the new database, inform the user that the database needs to migrate, and do it. Or ask if the customer would like to migrate because a new version was detected. @Fabio Cardoso

Comment: I was thinking do it during the splash screen when the app loads, i'll check what is the best option.

Comment: You can't run any code when the real "splash screen" (Default.png) is being shown.  The earliest opportunity you have to run anything is applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions, but if you take too long to show a UI, the system will kill your app.  Your best bet is to make the initial view controller a splash screen-esque view, which says "please wait" while you hit the network. But don't take too long!

Comment: @jsd how can I do that? Do you have any example? I'm doing it in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and it 'freezes' in the splash screen until the download is done. The DB has at the moment 5mb's, so it's the time it take to download that. Do you think apple will reject my app because that? How people usually do to update the DB after release the app? Thank you

Comment: I don't have an example handy. Just make a view controller that shows a UIProgressView. Run your db update in the background (NSOperation maybe?) so it doesn't freeze the app. Provide a way for the user to cancel. Download updates in the background when you have a chance and let the user know updated data is available when it's done. Basically, don't make the user wait if you can help it.

Comment: That sounds nice, but I have one problem, if I don't have the DB, I can't do nothing in my app, it's a kind of city guide that load all the content from the DB. I can't let the user use the app without it, or he will not enjoys the blank views then.

Comment: I would build a default DB into the app so they can do *something* without waiting. 5MB is not that big really. But, it's up to you. If you want to ship it empty and wait for it to populate on first run, go ahead, but implement some kind of loading screen so the user knows that they can't do anything. Maybe show some images showing how to use the app once the data is there.